# Asymptotic expansion of $ \int_{a}^{x} t^{t} ~ \mathrm{d}{t} $ as $ x \to \infty $.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I am trying to solve Exercise Problem 1.13 from Estrada and Kanwal’s *A Distributional Approach to Asymptotics, Theory and Applications* without any luck. Actually, I think that it is wrong.

> **Problem.** Prove the following asymptotic expansion as $ x $ goes to $ \infty $:
>   $$
>      \int_{a}^{x} t^{t} ~ \mathrm{d}{t}
> \sim x^{x} - x^{x - 1} \ln x + x^{x - 2} (\ln^{2} x - \ln x + 1) + \cdots.
> $$

My approach was integration by parts to find a recursion formula, but any way I do it, the first term that I get is always $ x^{x + 1} $, not $ x^{x} $ (that is why I think the problem could be wrong).

Can anyone point out the mistake, either from the book or mine? If I am wrong, what approach should I take?

Comment: The result is wrong. $t\log t$ on $[a,x]$ sharply peaks at $x$, so $I\sim \int_0^{\epsilon}x^xe^{-(1+\log x)t}\sim \frac {x^x}{1+\log x}$. You can check the correctness by applying the L'Hopital's rule to the RHS/LHS. Generally, $$\int_a^x e^{S(t)}\,dt\sim \frac {e^{S(x)}}{S'(x)}$$ for monotonic $S(x)=\omega(x)$.

Comment: That should read $S(x)=\omega(\log(x))$, that is $e^{S(t)}$ is super-polynomial.